# jquery click event handler is not called though registered

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

This happens in my wordpress site after upgrading to woocommerce 3.0.

HTML is:

```
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li><img src="<source>" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li>
    <li><img src="<source>" draggable="false"></li>
    <li><img src="<source>" draggable="false"></li>
</ol>
```

In chrome dev tools, when I inspect the ol element I see it has a registered click event handler, but when I click one of the images nothing happens. Tried adding a break point at the callback beginning, did not stop there.

This happens in IE, firefox and chrome so definitely something in the code is bad.

The java script code is from http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html

to clarify a bit more, the problem here that when i click the navigation bar images the click event does nothing, and the image does not change.

I have debugged it further more and discovered this: it seems the event is firing, but jquery doesn't trigger the callback. clicking on one of the navigation images, the click event's path array argument finishes at the li element, not img. this is problematic because further down the jquery code (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js:394) the current element (li, the last one in the path) is passed as a seed to the find function, which doesn't find anything since the selector used to register the event (in jquery .delegate()) is "a, img" so that returns empty and the event's callback is not called.

so, I guess the question now is why when I click the img, the li element "captures" the event and not the img?

Thanks

Comment: You might do better say what effect is missing rather than focus on a specific handler - that handler could come from any number of places.

Comment: Also, a click on a child element can have the event propagation stopped before reaching the parent (either at the `img` or `li` level). The handler may also be looking for a click on a specific sort of child as opposed to just any click before firing.

Comment: I think the problem is you said you register event on "ol" so don't expect to receive it on "img" maybe this $("ol omg").on('click',...) will do the job... am I right?

Comment: You should include the jQuery code in the question: *Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*

Comment: Hi, the code belongs to an external library, i've added a link to it in the post itself. will update about the desired behaviour. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, my img elements had a css property: "pointer-events: none;"

removing this solved the issue.

further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events